# .remove() in Python list breaks a for loop

Tags: python, list

I wrote a `for` loop that supposedly removes any elements that fits the description.

Example:

```
for tag in tags:
    if tag.lower() in ['ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3']:
        tags.remove(tag)
```

My `tags` would look like `['EX1', 'EX2', 'ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4', 'ex5']` and I expect to keep only `ex4` and `ex5`

What I noticed is that the for loop would skip some elements, giving me results like `['EX2', 'ex2', 'ex4', 'ex5']`

I suspect this being indexing issue, but I'm not sure if that's really the case.

I ended up using a list comprehension, which does the job correctly, but I just want to understand the true reason behind the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a hard time iterating through something that is being changed during the iteration.  You can instead use a copy:

```
for tag in tags[:]:
    if tag.lower() in ['ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3']:
        tags.remove(tag)
```

Comment: yea I used a list comprehension at the end. `tags = [tag for tag in tags if tag.lower() not in ['ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3']]` Just want to understand the reason behind it. Thanks!